# Syntax Error in JSON (even though it works in FF - I think)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Standard disclaimer, I'm not very good with JS/front end stuff, so I'm probably doing something dumb. I haven't worked with AJAX in a long time.
OK, so I am just in the process of fleshing out some initial ajax for an internal site I'm working on.  I've been testing in FF mostly and it seems ok, but when I try it in any other (real) browser, it fails with a syntax error. This is being done in Slim Framework and using TWIG for views.

```
$("#id").on('change', function(){   
    var v = $('#id option:selected').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path_for('inventory.ajax') }}", 
        data: {
            id: v
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
    })

    .done(function( result ) {
        $.each(result,function(key, val){ 
            var newA = JSON.stringify(val.property.property);

            $(".ajax").append(JSON.parse(newA) + ", ");
        });
    })


    .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
       alert( errorThrown );
       console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
       console.log( "Status: " + status );
       console.dir( xhr );
    })
});
```

My PHP code is simply:

```
public function ajax_getProps($request, $response) {
    $id = $request->getParam('id');

    $propertiesList = $this->c->helpers->getPropertyList($id);

    echo json_encode($propertiesList);
}
```

Now like I say, in FF it works, although I have a different question about why I have to stringify and then parse something just to output it.
When I run it in Chrome, or Edge - IE of course is useless and I don't care, I get the following message:
Syntax Error: Unexpected Token < in JSON at Position 0.
I've read that usually means you're returning HTML when it's expecting pure JSON, but I'm not. Am I?
The error appears to point to the following line:

```
console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
```

If I comment out that and the one below it, I still get the error message in the alert, but it does not show up in the console.

I've retrieved the JSON from dev tools and tested it in JSONLint and it says it's valid.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: show us some of your data, just example of json maybe? try not to JSON.parse the value

Answer (score 0):

......

Well I figured out the stupid thing I was doing.  I wasn't signed in on the other browsers and it was a making the ajax call to the protected route but the home page, where the call originated wasn't...